# unable to sort time(varchar type) by am/pm in query

Tags: mysql

I have some data in database where i need to sort time by am/pm .

My Code

```
$current_dat=date("m/d/Y");
```

$current_dat_short = substr($current_dat,0,2);

$rest = substr($current_dat,-7,2);

```
$sql_timesheet=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM timesheet WHERE reg_id='.$regiD.' AND MONTH(date)='.$current_month.' AND YEAR(date)='.$current_year.' ORDER BY date DESC');
while($res_timesheet=mysql_fetch_array($sql_timesheet)){
    $projID=$res_timesheet['project'];
    $taskID=$res_timesheet['task'];
    $editableid=$res_timesheet['id'];
```

above query sorts time by

```
01:20 AM
01:25 PM        
03:25 AM
03:40 AM
04:20 PM
```

but i need the output like

```
01:20 AM        
03:25 AM
03:40 AM
01:25 PM
04:20 PM.
```

pls do help me in this issue

Comment: You do not _actually_ have time values stored as `01:20 AM`, do you …?

Comment: Do ***NOT*** store times in a varchar column. Use the `TIME` data type.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Even i tried with that but no solution till now , much weird pls help

Comment: "*much wierd*" is not a valid MySQL error message. Please show us a complete example on SQLFiddle that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using the [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function in **MySQL**:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('10.00pm','%h.%i%p');
```

Try changing your query statement like this:

**UPDATED:**
Statement :

```
$sql_timesheet = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM timesheet WHERE reg_id=".$regiD." AND MONTH(date)=".$current_month." AND YEAR(date)=".$current_year." order by STR_TO_DATE(date,'%h.%i%p') desc,start_time asc");
```

Comment: Change your statement as `sql_timesheet = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM timesheet WHERE reg_id=".$regiD." AND MONTH(date)=".$current_month." AND YEAR(date)=".$current_year." order by STR_TO_DATE(date,'%h.%i%p') desc,start_time asc");`

Comment: Hi @basky 
since your time format is in this pattern ---01:20 AM   --
so STR_TO_DATE function should be in this pattern i.e    
STR_TO_DATE('01:20 AM','%h:%i%p');

so the query would be 

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM timesheet WHERE reg_id=".$regiD." AND MONTH(date)=".$current_month." AND YEAR(date)=".$current_year." order by STR_TO_DATE(date,'%h:%i%p') ASC");